# How to add sliding drawer in ScrollView?

Tags: eclipse, scrollview, slidingdrawer

I am currently working on an Android app and I am trying to add a sliding drawer in the scroll view, but when I did that it didn't display anything.
Here is my code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/japan_background"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <TableRow>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/jurong_west"
            android:tint="#55ff0000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFF00"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="  Address: Jurong West Sports &amp;
                Recretion Centre
                20 Jurong West St 93 #04-01
                Singapore 648965
                Tel: 6795 9162 " >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/leisure_park"
            android:tint="#55ff0000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFF00"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="  Address: Kallang Leisure Park
                5 Stadium Walk #04-01/02
                Singapore 397693
                Tel: 6887 1897 " >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/tampines_swimming"
            android:tint="#55ff0000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFF00"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="  Address: Tampines Swimming Complex
                BLK 505 Tampones Ave 5 #01-03/04
                Singapore 529652
                Tel: 6260 8197 " >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/yio_chu_kang"
            android:tint="#55ff0000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFF00"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="  Address: Yio Chu Kang Stadium
                2210 Ang Mo Kio Ave 9 #01-212
                Singapore 569777
                Tel: 6555 3655 " >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout></ScrollView>
```

Technically, I need to implement a sliding drawer to allow users to click on a different button once they have viewed this layout.

Please help me.